# how do i calculate all the total orders together?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prac3_Q2_JasmineLimSmith {
    Scanner scan;
    String set;
    int setA = 0, setB = 0, setC = 0, setD = 0;

    void createFile() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("orders.txt");
        scan = new Scanner(file);
    }

    void readData() {
        setA = scan.nextInt();
        setB = scan.nextInt();
        setC = scan.nextInt();
        setD = scan.nextInt();
        if (scan.hasNextLine())
            scan.nextLine();
    }

    void calcOrder() {
        double order = ((setA * 9.90) + (setB * 10.90) + (setC * 11.90) + (setD * 12.90));
        double totalOrder = (order);
        System.out.println("Set A " + setA);
        System.out.println("Set B " + setB);
        System.out.println("Set C " + setC);
        System.out.println("Set D " + setD);
        System.out.printf("Total price: %.2f", order);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Prac3_Q2_JasmineLimSmith cc = new Prac3_Q2_JasmineLimSmith();
        cc.createFile();
        for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= 10; cnt++) {
            cc.readData();
            cc.calcOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the sample output**

```
Set A 1
Set B 4
Set C 3
Set D 2
Total price: 115.00
```

Sorry, Im new to java, This is my code so far.

In total there would be 10 outputs like that one.

how would i take all the total prices and calculate it into 1 grand total at the very end?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: Aren't you already doing that (10 times, for some reason)? What output do you expect instead of the one you're currently getting?

Comment: Let calcOrder return the calculated value and add it to a variable in your for loop in main

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca its what my practice question asked for. It gave me a file and i have to read the file and calculate the total prices. then the question im asking is how do i calculate the grand total of the total prices. if that makes sense

Comment: When dealing with money, you should not use `double` type but `BigDecimal`, `int` or `long`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you allowed to change the return types of any methods, or add new parameters/methods? Since this seems like homework, I'll give you a general idea of two possible similar approaches.

One way to do this would be to return the total price from `calcOrder` (by changing the `void` return type to `double`). You can then declare an `double sumOfOrders = 0` variable outside of your loop where you call `calcOrder` and then keep adding the return value of `calcOrder` to it. At the end of the loop, you will have the sum of all orders which you can print out.

For example:

```java
    double calcOrder() { // note that the return type has been changed from 'void' to 'double'
        double order = ((setA * 9.90) + (setB * 10.90) + (setC * 11.90) + (setD * 12.90));
        // print statements
        return order; 
    }
```

Then, in your main function, you can use the return value when calling `calcOrder()`:

```java
      double sumOfOrders = 0;
      for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= 10; cnt++) {
          cc.readData();
          // The following can alternatively be written as
          // sumOfOrders += cc.calcOrder();
          sumOfOrders = sumOfOrders + cc.calcOrder();
      }
      System.out.printf("Sum of all orders: %.2f", sumOfOrders);
```

If you are not allowed to change the return types of existing methods, you could:

1. Make `order` an instance variable (e.g. `private double orderPrice;`
2. Set `order` to the sum of all prices (e.g. `this.orderPrice = ((setA * 9.90) + ...);`)
3. Add a getter for the `orderPrice` variable (e.g. by adding a `double getOrderPrice() { return this.orderPrice; }` method in your `Prac3_Q2_JasmineLimSmith` class)
4. Sum the orders in the same way as above:

```java
      double sumOfOrders = 0;
      for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= 10; cnt++) {
          cc.readData();
          cc.calcOrder();
          sumOfOrders = sumOfOrders + cc.getOrderPrice(); 
      }
      System.out.printf("Sum of all orders: %.2f", sumOfOrders);
```

Comment: Could you show a small example? i dont quite follow for the first approach u mentioned

Comment: Sure. I've updated the answer with some example code. Let me know if you have any further questions.